# GCSE works only on one page - then it disappears

Tags: html, google-custom-search, gitbook

I wanted to add an Google CSE to the gitbook instead of the normal search engine.
It's no problem to add the GCSE to the gitbook, only the result is weird.

If I go directly to a page I can see the Search Box and can use it normally. If I look at the code there is a div: `<div id="__gcse_0">`.

If I now go through another chapter the Search Box disappears and there is another div instead of the previous in the code: `<gcse:search>`.

After I refresh the page the box appears again. This happens on Firefox and Chrome.

Do somebody know what the problem might be?

Comment: You need to elaborate. Show more code.

Comment: What do you need? Which part of code can I add?

Comment: as much relevant code as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure out this same issue... So far, I can only get it to stay by placing the google script into an [overriding layout.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003051/not-able-to-add-custom-template-files-in-gitbook-themes/30657283#30657283) - but this is not recommended, and it isn't ideal for most placements. I've also noticed that the CSS that is loaded through the script then gets lost when switching pages (like the script itself was previously) so this solution would also be a pain to re-add all the css files. So it's a super messy solution, and hopefully some one has a better solution out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is still there and I can't manage to fix it. 
There is one other possibility, which is also not ideal: You can let the page refresh each time you change the chapter. This way the google search ig back again